# Is there a name for this stochastic process?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, bernoulli-numbers

Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$ be a probability space and $\{X_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ be a stochastic process. Assume each $X_n$ only takes two values $0$ or $1$, i.e., $X_n:\Omega\rightarrow \{0,1\}$. Of course if $\{X_n\}$ are independently and identically distributed, then this is just Bernoulli trial.

Instead, assume this process is not necessarily i.i.d. But it satisfies $$P\big(X_{n+1}=1\big|X_1,X_2,\cdots, X_n\big)=P\big(X_{n+1}=1\big|\sum_{l=1}^n X_l\big).$$ That is the distribution of $X_{n+1}$ given $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ only depends on the sum of $X_1,\cdots,X_n$.

I think if we write $S_n=\sum_{l=1}^n X_n$, then $\{S_n\}$ is just an inhomogeneous Markov chain, with initial state $S_0\equiv 0$. My question is whether there is a formal name for this process, or whether there is some study on the asymptotic behavior of this process. Thanks!

Comment: We usually use the term "homogeneous" to refer to time homogeneity; that is, the transition probabilities (or rates) are constant in time.  As you have defined this, $\{S_n\}$ looks like just a discrete-time pure birth process, with state-dependent birth probabilities.

Comment: Thanks. The birth probability not only depends on state but also on time. So it is possible that $P(S_{n+1}=k+1|S_n=k)\neq P(S_{m+1}=k+1|S_m=k)$ for $n\geq m$. That's why I used inhomogeneous Markov chain.

Comment: Where's the dependence on time?